# How to setup a many to many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I had to change a one to many to a many to many relationship. With the former A user was assigned a `companyId` upon registering. The only documents they could return from the database was controlled with a where statement in my Web API. Now that a user can be assigned many companies I need to change that where statement to do the same thing. So far I have created the junction table. I am having problems accessing it and returning it correctly.

Company class:

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public int UserCompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserCompany UserCompany { get; set; }
 }
```

`User` class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity>
        GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager
            .CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public int UserCompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserCompany UserCompany { get; set; }
}
```

Junction table:

```
public class UserCompany
{
    [Key]
    public int UCompanyId { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

ApiController

```
 public IEnumerable<Document> GetDocuments()
 {
     var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
     var user = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

     using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
     {
         return context.UserCompanies
                       .Where(j => j.CompanyId == user.UserCompany.CompanyId)
                       .ToList();
     }
}
```

The error is appearing at the `.ToList()` call:

> Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TransparentEnergy.Models.UserCompany>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TransparentEnergy.Models.Document>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Update

```
// GET api/<controller>
public List<Document> GetDocuments()
{
    var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
    var user = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

    using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        return context.Documents
                      .Where(j => j.CompanyId == user.UserCompany.UCompanyId)
                      .ToList();
    }
}
```

`Document` class:

```
public class Document
{
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DocumentDate { get; set; }
    public string DocumentUrl { get; set; }
    public DateTime DocumentUploadDate { get; set; }
    public string DocumentUploadedBy { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

I changed `IEnumerable` to `List`. I am still not doing it right, I am getting an error in my `ApiController`

> Non-static method requires a target.

I posted my `Document` class as well. I am lost on how to make this work. First time with a many to many relationship

Here is the stacktrace

> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.TryGetFieldOrPropertyValue(MemberExpression me, Object instance, Object& memberValue)
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.TryEvaluatePath(Expression expression, ConstantExpression& constantExpression)
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression.EvaluateParameter(Object[] arguments)
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6()
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()
> at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator>b__0()
> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
> at TransparentEnergy.ControllersAPI.apiDocumentUserController.GetDocuments() in c:\Development\TransparentEnergy\TransparentEnergy\ControllersAPI\apiDocumentUserController.cs:line 29
> at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
> at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
> at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
> at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're returning a List and the type your function return is IEnumerable, try:

```
public List<Document> GetDocuments()
    {
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var user = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            return context.UserCompanies
                .Where(j => j.CompanyId == user.UserCompany.CompanyId)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put some buildable code, I tried to put all together but it's missing some classes like _UserManager_ and _IdentityUser_. 


Anyway, this kind of error occurs when you try to use a method of a class that wasn't instantiated yet or the method isn't static to you without instantiate it.

Comment: Anyway, this kind of error occurs when you try to use a method of a class that wasn't instantiated yet or the method isn't static to you without instantiate it

Comment: i put them in here. let me know if you need anything else. thanks http://plnkr.co/edit/ScFHxVWvSfEStsClRQeB?p=preview

Comment: Man, I'm really want to help you, but I'm want to put effort on solve the problem not to find it, build a solution with the problem and I'll look into it, the files don't even has the using statements....